# loading contents of text file inside a div javascript for editing

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to edit a text file by loading it inside a div. After loading the div changes into text area for editing purpose.
Here is the html code:

```
<input type="button" value="view" onclick="load_file('let it go');"></input>
<input type="button" value="edit" onclick="edit_file('let it go');"></input>
<div class="content style" style="height: 300px; width: 300px"></div>
```

Here is my javascript function for loading file into div

```
    function load_file(id){
            $.ajax({
                url : id+".txt",
                dataType: "text",
                success : function (data) {
                    $(".content").html(data);                 
                }
            });
        }
```

and my javascript function for editing file

```
  function edit_file(id){
            divHtml = $(".content").html();
            divHtml = $.trim(divHtml);
            if(divHtml.length<=0){
                load_file(id);       
            }           
            $(".content").text();
            console.log(divHtml);
            var edit = $("<textarea class='content style'/>");
            edit.val(divHtml);
            $(".content").replaceWith(edit);
            edit.focus();
        }
```

When I click the view button it is working fine. When the edit button is clicked for the first time it isn't working, but when its clicked for the second time it is working.

Can any one help me with this? I want to display the content for editing for the first time too when I click the edit button.

Comment: you can pass a callback to load_file, or duplicate its ajax code in edit_file

Comment: Not getting quite getting what you are doing, but did you missed? `contenteditable` inside div to make it editable

Comment: i am converting the div into a textarea. so i think there is no need of contenteditable for the div.

Comment: Your code works fine. It shows content in textarea on edit button click. Check your console if there is any log

Comment: @apb: Still it is not working for the first time when i click the edit button.

Comment: have you checked console? is there any logs?

Comment: when the button is clicked for the first time it is giving the divHtml value as nothing in the console, and for the second time it is giving the contents of the file in the log.